# React Hooks Mathematics

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am brand new to React in general, especially hooks. I am trying to do a very simple algebraic expression on an input form. Ideally, I'd have it automatically update without a calculate button. When I did that I got some weird results that made no mathematical sense. Forgive me for not being able to explain this further, I am an idiotic total loss!

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./App.css";

import MaskedInput from "react-text-mask";
import NumberFormat from "react-number-format";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import InputAdornment from "@material-ui/core/InputAdornment";
import AttachMoneyIcon from "@material-ui/icons/AttachMoney";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

// import { evaluate } from "mathjs";

// import Input from "./components/inputs/input-field.component";

function TextMaskCustom(props) {
  const { inputRef, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <MaskedInput
      {...other}
      ref={(ref) => {
        inputRef(ref ? ref.inputElement : null);
      }}
      mask={[
        "(",
        /[1-9]/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        ")",
        " ",
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        "-",
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
        /\d/,
      ]}
      placeholderChar={"\u2000"}
      showMask
    />
  );
}

TextMaskCustom.propTypes = {
  inputRef: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

function NumberFormatCustom(props) {
  const { inputRef, onChange, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <NumberFormat
      {...other}
      getInputRef={inputRef}
      onValueChange={(state) => {
        onChange({
          target: {
            name: props.name,
            value: state.value,
          },
        });
      }}
      thousandSeparator
      isNumericString
    />
  );
}

NumberFormatCustom.propTypes = {
  inputRef: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

function FormattedInputs() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    numberformatOH: "150",
    numberformatThird: "30",
    numberformatAvgGross: "38",
    numberformatMin: "20",
    numberformatGoal: "200",
    numberformatMnth: "", // add this values to the state
    numberformatYrly: "",
  });
  
  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.state,
    });
    return state;
  };

  // const x = Number(state.numberformatAvgGross);
  // const y = Number(state.numberformatGoal);
  // const z = Number(state.numberformatAvgGross);
  
  const onButtonClick = () => {

    
    const numberformatMnth = (
      Number(state.numberformatAvgGross) * 
      Number(state.numberformatGoal) - 
      Number(state.numberformatAvgGross)) / 
      4;
    const numberformatYrly = 12 * (
      Number(state.numberformatAvgGross) * 
      Number(state.numberformatGoal)) - 
      12 * Number(state.numberformatAvgGross);
    setState({
      ...state,
      numberformatMnth,
      numberformatYrly, // update this values when button clicked
    });
    console.log(numberformatYrly);
    console.log(numberformatMnth);
    return state;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>OrderHound Savings Calculator</h1>
        <body>
          <div>
            <form>
              <div className="input">
                <TextField
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <AttachMoneyIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                    inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
                  }}
                  label="OrderHound Cost"
                  id="outlined-size-numberformatOH"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={state.numberformatOH}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  name="numberformatOH"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input">
                <TextField
                  InputProps={{
                    inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
                  }}
                  label="3rd Party Percentage Cost"
                  id="outlined-size-numberformatThird"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={state.numberformatThird}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  name="numberformatThird"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input">
                <TextField
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <AttachMoneyIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                    inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
                  }}
                  label="Average Sales Gross"
                  id="outlined-size-numberformatAvgGross"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={state.numberformatAvgGross}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  name="numberformatAvgGross"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="online-orders">
                <TextField
                  InputProps={{
                    inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
                  }}
                  label="Minimum Number of Orders"
                  id="outlined-size-numberformatMin"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={state.numberformatMin}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  name="numberformatMin"
                />
                <TextField
                  InputProps={{
                    inputComponent: NumberFormatCustom,
                  }}
                  label="Goal Number of Orders"
                  id="outlined-size-numberformatGoal"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={state.numberformatGoal}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  name="numberformatGoal"
                />
              </div>
              <div className="savings">
                <TextField
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <AttachMoneyIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                    readOnly: true,
                  }}
                  label="Monthly Savings"
                  id="outlined-size-read-only-numberformatMnth"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={state.numberformatMnth}
                  // onButtonClick={savingsMnth}
                  name="numberformatMnth"
                />
                <TextField
                  InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: (
                      <InputAdornment position="start">
                        <AttachMoneyIcon />
                      </InputAdornment>
                    ),
                    readOnly: true,
                  }}
                  label="Yearly Savings"
                  id="outlined-size-read-only-numberformatYrly"
                  variant="outlined"
                  value={state.numberformatYrly}
                  // onButtonClick={savingsYrly}
                  name="numberformatYrly"
                />
              </div>
              <Button
                className="button"
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                size="large"
                onClick={onButtonClick}
              >
                Calculate
              </Button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </body>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormattedInputs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the calculated values in the state and call `handleChange` to change them when button was clicked. It would be something like this:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  numberformatOH: "150",
  numberformatThird: "30",
  numberformatAvgGross: "38",
  numberformatMin: "20",
  numberformatGoal: "200",
  numberformatMnth: "0", // add this values to the state
  numberformatYrly: "0",
});

const x = Number(state.numberformatAvgGross);
const y = Number(state.numberformatGoal);
const z = Number(state.numberformatAvgGross);

const handleChange = (event) => {
  setState({
    ...state,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.state,
  });
  return state;
};

const onButtonClick = (x, y, z) => {
  const numberformatMnth = (x * y - z) / 4;
  const numberformatYrly = 12 * (x * y) - 12 * z;
  setState({
    ...state,
    numberformatMnth,
    numberformatYrly, // update this values when button clicked
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes a lot more sense, I am however getting NaN back as a result. Any idea why?

Comment: Show me please how you use `onButtonClick`

Comment: Try not to pass to `onButtonClick` any arguments: `const onButtonClick = () => {...}`. I think you pass to button and it gets `event` as first parameter. That's why you have `NaN`

Comment: Is there a way I can post the whole app component here?

Comment: Yes, you can pass using pastebin.com and give me a link to the code

Comment: I just edited the question to have the whole component. I really, really apreciate the help. I am getting some weird calculations when it does produce a number. I would think having a math minor would have helped do simple algebra in react! lol

Comment: Sorry, can you load your project to codesandbox.io? I can't figure out why there is a problem

Comment: https://pastebin.com/h6uXEMgy, I never heard of pastebin, that's absolutely amazing.  Thank you for even more knowledge than I expected!

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-pasteur-w5n5z?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used code sandbox much, there are some dependency issues

Comment: Look, that's working example https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-shape-tuib4?file=/src/App.js

Comment: You have been unbelievably helpful, I will have to look through it closely to see all that you changed and figure out why I am getting strange things with the math.  For instance, it is taking the intitial state, multiplying it by 4, then adding some weird number that I can't figure out. You have been unreasonably helpful though! Thank you again!!!

Comment: You are welcome! The best thanks is mark the useful answers as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` with your input values as dependencies in the following form:

```
const [calculatedResult, setCalculatedResult] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    setCalculatedResult(a+b);
}, [a, b]);
```